# POWER BI calculating new column that will show MAX value of another column by year and will show it for every month in a year

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I need to calculate MAX value of particular column by year and pass it to another column that will show me that MAX value for every month in this year. Here is what I need:

| date | value | max_of_value1_in_year_for_every_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 5 | 56 |
| 01.02.2022 | 3 | 56 |
| 01.03.2022 | 2 | 56 |
| 01.04.2022 | 3 | 56 |
| 01.05.2022 | 4 | 56 |
| 01.06.2022 | 5 | 56 |
| 01.07.2022 | 56 | 56 |
| 01.08.2022 | 6 | 56 |
| 01.09.2022 | 7 | 56 |
| 01.10.2022 | 7 | 56 |
| 01.11.2022 | 3 | 56 |
| 01.12.2022 | 1 | 56 |
| 01.01.2023 | 99 | 99 |
| 01.02.2023 | 8 | 99 |
| 01.03.2023 | 7 | 99 |
| 01.04.2023 | 6 | 99 |
| 01.05.2023 | 4 | 99 |
| 01.06.2023 | 2 | 99 |
| 01.07.2023 | 11 | 99 |
| 01.08.2023 | 1 | 99 |
| 01.09.2023 | 11 | 99 |

community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Finding-the-maximum-value-within-a-12-month-date-range/m-p/2593696

Answer (score 1):

1. In Power Query populate month, year columns from Date column.
2. Concatenate above two columns with hyphen - and name it as Month column
3. In Data View, create a calculated column using DAX

   `Column = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[value]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Month]))`

[image]

Comment: maybe it may work but I am getting error "the end of input was reached".
My DAX is correct, what should I check more?

Comment: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Studio-error-quot-The-end-of-input-was-reached-quot/td-p/2235637

Comment: I have tried that before but it does not work

Comment: Mentality is almost correct . Instead of creating a month column, build a year column called [Year]. Then write this dax:MaxValue = CALCULATE(
    MAX(YourTable[value]),
    ALLEXCEPT(YourTable,YourTable[Year])
)

Answer (score 0):

**1. add one column:**

```
Year = YEAR([date])
```

**2. calculate Max:**

```
Max = CALCULATE(MAXX('Table', 
[value]),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Year]))
```

[image]